# Get values of different elements with $(this)

Tags: jquery

EDIT: Solved!, I also updated the code for the future. when someone will look for this kind of problem.

Thanks to: [Nesaje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246088/nesaje)

I have a div that is generated using a loop. Inside that div there is a `fieldset` element for radio buttons and a text input. I can get the radio button value with the `change` event, but I can't get the text input. The radio buttons and text are generated from loop so I don't have specific ID.

```js
$("body").on("change", "#star-rate input:radio", function(e) {
  var score = $(this).val();
  var comment = $(this)
    .parents('.row.stars-comment-container') // Find common parent container (notice class name ;)
    .find('input[name=comment]')                         // Once there, find input with name = comment (name can be duplicated)
    .val();
  console.log('comment: ' + comment + ' - score:' + score);
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div class="col-12" id="star-rate" style="padding-top:10px">
  <div class="row stars-comment-container">
  <!-- (Genarated via loop)This is expected to be repeated => stars and comments together. -->
    <div style="padding-top:7px; width:110px"><span class="pull-right" style="font-size:16px"><b>Rate:&nbsp;</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="star-rate">
      <fieldset class="rate">
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="5.00" />
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="4.00" />
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="3.00" />
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="2.00" />
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="1.00" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Moved inside common parent container -->
  <!-- class="col-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment"></div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: What are you expecting `$(this).find('txt-comment')` to do? `txt-comment` is an invalid selector, and even if it was an id or class there's no matching elements in your HTML

Comment: `$(this).find('txt-comment');` That is saying look for the "<text-comment>" element that is a *Child* of the radio button that was selected. I doubt a radio button has a child and I do not think you have a text-comment element.

Comment: Hi sorry I meant ('commen't) - *edited the question* So I can I select the text input within the div? sorry for the code I am just doing try and error with the $(this) and find

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer based on comment and fact there will be more groups of stars and comments.

I've modified slightly HTML provided like this (to bring stars and comment into the same container, removed comment id, as that cannot be duplicated).

```
    <div class="col-12" id="star-rate" style="padding-top:10px">
  <div class="row stars-comment-container"> <!-- This is expected to be repeated => stars and comments together. -->
    <div style="padding-top:7px; width:110px"><span class="pull-right" style="font-size:16px"><b>Rate:&nbsp;</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="star-rate">
      <fieldset class="rate">
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="5.00" />
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="4.00" />
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="3.00" />
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="2.00" />
        <input type="radio" data-id="{{$fA->id}}" id="s5-{{$fA->id}}" name="score" value="1.00" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Moved inside common parent container -->
  <!-- class="col-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment"></div> -->
</div>
```

With this in place, consider the following JS snippet

```
$("body").on("change", "#star-rate input:radio", function(e) {
  var score = $(this).val();
  var comment = $(this)
    .parents('.row.stars-comment-container') // Find common parent container (notice class name ;)
    .find('input[name=comment]')                         // Once there, find input with name = comment (name can be duplicated)
    .val();
  console.log('comment: ' + comment + ' - score:' + score);
});
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Nesaje, thank you for the help, the problem is i have multiple comment (that are generated with loop) thats why im having hard time getting the specific value.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment. I hope you can update HTML code to make it like in the snippet above.

Comment: That's fast, Will try this tomorrow morning.. Looks like this is the answer. Thanks again Nesaje

Comment: Hello Nesaje, Thanks! your code works! I also updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

although I am still not sure what exactly you want, but what I am getting by your question that on form Submit you need this value in Text field,
or if you want to just get the text input value you can do this on keyup.
So in case 1, when you need to get the comment on submit of form:

```
$(selector).submit(function(){
    var textVal = $('#comment').val();
});
```

and for case 2 you can use keyup when user is typing:

```
$("body").on("keyup", "#comment", function(e) {
   var textValue= $(this).val();
   console.log('comment: ' + textValue);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Atul I am getting a clue now In your 2nd example. But what I want is to get the value of the comment at the same with the radio change event. (edited the question for more detailed) Thanks again